# Make an Argument Optional in Python

Tags: python, arguments

I'm making a Script with a GUI Box in a CAD program, and the User selects  about 7 different surfaces in the viewport.  I then pass those values onto another Function when the User hits "OK"

The function that it is passed to looks like this

```
def MeshingTools(od_idSurf, trgSurf, PipeBodySurf, sealSurf, threadSurf, BodySurf, cplgEndSurf):
```

The problem is: if the user does not need to select one of those surfaces, I get a error saying, `MeshingTools()` takes exactly 7 non-keyword arguments (2 given)

How can I get around this issue?

UPDATE:

I tried keyword arguments and am not quite getting what I need.

`def MeshingTools(**kwargs):
print kwargs`

When I just select 1 surface, I get the following out

`{'PipeBodySurf': (mdb.models['FullCAL4'].rootAssembly.instances['PinNew-1'].edges[151], mdb.models['FullCAL4'].rootAssembly.instances['PinNew-1'].edges[153])}`

if I try to print PipeBodySurf , it says that global name is not defined.

Any ideas?

FINAL UPDATE (SOLVED)

Now I see that `**kwargs` creates a dictionary, so instead of using just the parameter name in the rest of the code, you have to use `kwargs['parameter']`  and then it will use the values

Comment: How are you passing the values to the function?

Comment: Have you tried pasting your question's title into a Google search?

Comment: TigerhawkT3, yeah, but I could only find where you can overwrite the values, not what I want

Comment: If keyword arguments don't meet your needs, you need to tell us what you've tried and what you didn't like about them.

Comment: I guarantee you that this information was readily available. If you don't want your code to overwrite values, don't tell it to. You might be well-served by looking into the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: John,   yeah,  keyword arguments looks like they will work.... going to try it soon

Comment: ok, keyword arguments are not quite working... please look at my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arbitrary argument passing with `*` operation :

```
def MeshingTools(*args):
  for i in args:
      #do stuff with i
```

Functions can use special argument preceded with one or two `*` character to collect an arbitrary number of extra arguments. (`*` for positional arguments and `**` for keyword arguments)

Comment: people should lose 100 points for downvoting without comment.  WHY the downvote?!

Comment: The answer is rather barebones. Keyword arguments should be mentioned, if not preferred.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yeah you are right just added!

Comment: @ChrisHawkes Thanks, I should mentioned about keyword arguments too.